# React Native - binding a function to this

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using react native 0.48 and I was wondering if the following is possible.

So my intention is to make my code a little bit more reusable.
I have 4 classes each of them have similar code within componentDidMount.
They share similar code componentDidMount() but the rest of the code in the render method is a little different.

My idea was this to share code across classes:

```
class 1

        componentDidMount(){
        componentDidMountTemplate().bind(this);
      }
```

where inside componentDidMountTemplate(which is a just an exported function), code that uses "this" keyword that should operate on objects in class 1, or basically any class that calls and binds this

however the line componentDidMountTemplate().bind(this); generates this error:

> cannot call a class as a function

any solutions? ideas?

Comment: you are invoking the function instead of providing a reference `componentDidMountTemplate.bind(this);` but this won't bind it as you are not storing it anywhere

Comment: See my answer, the error you have suggest you have a problem other than just the bind.

Answer (score 2):

You are not binding anything, the bind method returns a new instance and you did not store it anywhere, and on top of that you did not run the bind on the function it self but instead you did it on the returned value of that function as you used the `()` and invoked it.
I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to reuse with your code as you didn't provide more details but basically you don't need to bind it at all and just pass the `this` object to the external function.

So you got 2 main options:

- bind the external function and store it inside your class that needs
  to invoke it. **and praying that anyone who will use your function
  will remember to bind it!!!**.
  If by any chance your external function `componentDidMountTemplate` in your case is declared as an arrow function then binding won't work, because arrow functions use `this` in a lexical context (see my example).
- Explicit pass the object as a parameter (which i find it the most
  readable and clear for consumers of this function util).

This is a snippet for just a small proof of concept:

```js
class MyClass {
  externalFunc = ref => {
    console.log("passing the this explicit as a parameter", ref.state);
  };

  externalFunc2() {
    // depending on bind and praying for the best!
    console.log("depending on bind ", this.state);
  }

  externalFunc3 = () => {
    // with arrow functions bind won't work
    //because `this` is bound in a lexical context
    console.log("arrow function", this.state);
  };
}

const MyClassInstance = new MyClass();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someValue: "123"
    };
    this.externalFunc2 = MyClassInstance.externalFunc2.bind(this);
    this.externalFunc3 = MyClassInstance.externalFunc3.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    MyClassInstance.externalFunc(this);
    this.externalFunc2();
    this.externalFunc3();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Look at the console!</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So im testing this and I think i might have misunderstood your answer.
basically I have some ListView instance in class1, and I used to populate it via the code that executes in the componentDidMount(). Now since I have a few classes using the same layout, I want to populate all their ListViews' using one codebase. I tried your way, but I the code the in componentDidMountTemplate, does not get invoked even after I save the variable in class 1 and invoke it.

Comment: i think a proper code example will help to clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class properties and define `componentDidMount` as an arrow function (instead of method) inside of your components. Arrow functions use lexical `this`, so you don't have to bother with function binding. For example:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  // you can access `this` safely
}
```

Comment: Using arrow functions for life cycle methods is technically doable, but [it is a little dangerous](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10810)

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMountTemplate().bind(this);`

should probably be

`this.componentDidMountTemplate = componentDidMountTemplate.bind(this);`

`.bind()` returns a new, bound function. You need to store that function in a value and then call it.

Now you can call `this.componentDidMountTemplate()`

Also anytime you write `()` next to a function, that function will be called

Comment: and where is `componentDidMountTemplate` is stored in `class 1`? the OP should shadow it somehow

Comment: actually your edit isn't a full solution yet. the OP should declare a function inside `class1` that invokes  `componentDidMountTemplate` and maybe passing the `this` object or binding it somehow

Comment: how is that? this effectively adds a method to the class called componentDidMountTemplate, bound to class 1. sorry I don't understand what's wrong with the code ^^ if it is bound in componentWillMount, then called in componentDidMount it would work no?

Comment: if `componentDidMountTemplate` is declared as an arrow function then it won't work because arrow functions use `this` in a lexical context. but in general this is the way to do it if you really want to use `bind`. i just wouldn't use it and prefer an explicit reference to the class / object via parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function and then invoke it immediately like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    (componentDidMountTemplate.bind(this))();
}
```

This consists of two parts -- first, binding the component context to the function (`.bind(this)`), and then second, invoking the returned function.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is suspicious. While you seem to be using `bind` incorrectly I would expect the error: `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Is your `componentDidMountTemplate` a class? I'm assuming you want to change that to a function and then follow the advice below regarding `bind`.

---

If you want to call the bound function you need the `()` after the `bind()`. Otherwise you are calling the unbound function and then trying to bind whatever is returned from it.

```
componentDidMount(){
    componentDidMountTemplate.bind(this)();
}
```

This means a new bound function is created, then called immediately

As many of the other answers are suggesting, it is common with React components to bind functions initially and store a reference to the bound function. However in your case you are likely only calling it once because the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method is only called once.